# Transition and translate3d horizontal slider animation issue

Tags: jquery, css, css-animations

I'm making infinity loop horizontal product slider for my shop and got stuck.

The problem is when there is no overflowed products on either side the insertBefore/After jQuery function will be called to move product from one side to another.

After product is moved, jQuery will disable transition and change CSS transform property which will hide product without animations, so user can't see that.

After moved product is hidden, transition is enabled again and transform property is changed again, but the product will move (because of changed transform), but it transition won't animate it...

I hope you understand what is my problem... Try to run my code and you will see.

I've tried to make it work by:

- changing inline CSS with css function
- adding and removing custom classes (addClass, removeClass, toggleClass).
- Spent few hours playing around and googling with no luck.

CSS:

```
      .mtt-product-slider-control-wrap {
    padding: 0px 20px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .mtt-product-slider-wrap {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 0;
  }
  .mtt-product-slider {
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
  }
  .mtt-product-wrap {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    background: yellow;
    padding: 25px;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: initial;
  }
  .mtt-product {
    background: red;
  }
  .mtt-product-slider-left {
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    background: #666;
    opacity: 0.8;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    margin-top: -15px;
    z-index: 100;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.4s;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: #fff;
  }
  .mtt-product-slider-right {
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    background: #666;
    opacity: 0.8;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 0;
    margin-top: -15px;
    z-index: 100;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.4s;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: #fff;
  }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container" style="margin-top: 300px;">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="mtt-product-slider-control-wrap">
      <div class="mtt-product-slider-left"></div>
      <div class="mtt-product-slider-right"></div>
    <div class="mtt-product-slider-wrap">
    <div class="mtt-product-slider">


      <div class="mtt-product-wrap">
        <div class="mtt-product">
          <p>PRODUCT 1</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="mtt-product-wrap">
        <div class="mtt-product">
          <p>PRODUCT 2</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="mtt-product-wrap">
        <div class="mtt-product">
          <p>PRODUCT 3</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="mtt-product-wrap">
        <div class="mtt-product">
          <p>PRODUCT 4</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="mtt-product-wrap">
        <div class="mtt-product">
          <p>PRODUCT 5</p>
        </div>
      </div>

</div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    var sliderWrapWidth = jQuery('.mtt-product-slider-wrap').width();
    var productWidth = sliderWrapWidth / 3;
    var productCount = jQuery('.mtt-product-wrap').length;
    var sliderWidth = productWidth * productCount;

    var stepCount = 0;

    var translate3dValue = 0;

    var productSlider = jQuery('.mtt-product-slider');

    productSlider.outerWidth(sliderWidth);

    jQuery('.mtt-product-wrap').each(function(){
      jQuery(this).outerWidth(productWidth);
    });

    jQuery('.mtt-product-slider-left').on('click', function() {
      stepCount++;
      if(stepCount == productCount - 2) {
        translate3dValue += productWidth;
        productSlider.css({
          transition: 'none',
          transform: 'translate3d(' + translate3dValue + 'px, 0px, 0px)'
        });
        jQuery('.mtt-product-wrap:last').insertBefore('.mtt-product-wrap:first');
        stepCount = productCount - 3;
      }
      translate3dValue -= productWidth;
      productSlider.css({
        transition: 'all 1000ms ease 0s',
        transform: 'translate3d(' + translate3dValue + 'px, 0px, 0px)'
      });
    });

    jQuery('.mtt-product-slider-right').on('click', function() {
      stepCount--;
      if(stepCount == -1) {
        translate3dValue -= productWidth;
        productSlider.css({
          transition: 'none',
          transform: 'translate3d(' + translate3dValue + 'px, 0px, 0px)'
        });
        jQuery('.mtt-product-wrap:first').insertAfter('.mtt-product-wrap:last');
        stepCount = 0;
      }
      translate3dValue += productWidth;
      productSlider.css({
        transition: 'all 1000ms ease 0s',
        transform: 'translate3d(' + translate3dValue + 'px, 0px, 0px)'
      });
    });

  });
```